# Calling Service From Broadcastreceiver not working as expected

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want my service to run at a time specified from alarm manager. But in my case its running on the time i have specified and also if i open the app after the time specified service runs. I want it to run only on the time specified and it should repeat everyday. I don't know what is wrong in the code i have written. Any help is appreciated.

This is my service class:

```
public class AutoLogout extends Service {

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    logoutUser();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);
    db.deleteData();
    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AutoLogout.class));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

This is my BroadcastReciever class:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "MyReceiver Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,AutoLogout.class);
        context.startService(intent1);
    }
}
```

CategoryActivity.java where i am calling alarm manager in oncreate method:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,46);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent);

}
}
```

This is in my manifest file:

```
    <service android:name=".services.AutoLogout" />
    <receiver android:name=".services.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Maybe this is for you? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Why are you using an Activity for resetting the Alarm? By the way, I doubt that CategoryActivity code compiles. You are executing code outside any method or ctor ... did you miss copying something?

Comment: @Fildor: where do i have to call the alarm to reset?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote Android code, but I guess it should be possible to do it in the service (without Activity). Just include it into logoutUser or create a method for it.

Comment: @Fildor : later i have to start the service in the activity is it?

Comment: Yes to initiate all , you have to start from activity. But to *reschedule* you don't need the activity. The activity should only be necessary to change the scheduled time.

Comment: @Fildor : Can u show me an example? Not getting it.

Comment: Ah, that would be too broad for me right now. Think of your activity as a configuration tool for the service. Have it just set the time of day and if there is not already an Alarm set, set it. That's it. Service then sets a new Alarm based on the configuration info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening because each time you open the activity which sets the alarm, it is re-initializing the alarm - however, the alarm is incorrectly firing right away each time you open the activity because the correct alarm time (14:46:00) has likely already passed on the current day, and when you set an `AlarmManager` alarm for a time that has already passed, it fires immediately.

In order to fix this, we need to check if the alarm time has already passed for the current day, and if it has, set the alarm for 14:46:00 on the **following** day:

```
if (cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Here is how it would look inside of your `CategoryActivity`:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_alarm.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); // i added this to ensure the calendar is being configured correctly
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,46);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

        //check if time has already passed today, adjust alarm to tomorrow if it has
        if (cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The `if` statement simply checks if the current time is larger than the time that `cal_alarm` is set for, and if it is, sets the alarm for 14:46:00 *tomorrow*.  If you need any more clarification feel free to ask!

Comment: `cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)` is this line setting the alarm on the same time for the next day??

Comment: Correct, this makes it set for the next day (not the 1st of the month like it might seem).  You check if the alarm time has already passed, and only add this line if the time has passed on the current day.